# Indenting part of a paragraph

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I'm trying to get this result in LateX. I've looked at a few questions about indenting an entire paragraph but can't find how to keep my abstract label at the margin and then indent the rest of the paragraph next to it. how would I achieve this?

[image: The result I'm trying to acheive]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I was just typing a comment on your other question, when it was deleted, thus I'm giving the info here: `\caption[Caption text for e.g. the list of figures, something like a title]{Caption text which will be placed after e.g. "Figure 9.5", explaining the picture, its details and so on. This might be a lot longer than the text for the list of figures.}` If only `\caption{Text}` is used, than "Text" is used for the list of figures (or list of tables, if it's a table and not a figure) as well as caption for the figure. When useing commands in the caption, it might be necessary to `\protect` them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing is to place the "title" into a \makebox to force it to be a certain width.  Whether you should tweak a number or solve for it using \settowidth is another issue.  One can use the plain TeX \hangindent (which goes away after one paragraph), a \parbox or a minipage.  The main difference is that you can't break a page in the middle of a \parbox or minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\parskip=\baselineskip
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\hangindent=.8in
\hangafter=1
\noindent\makebox[.8in][l]{Abstract:}\lipsum[1]

\noindent\makebox[.8in][l]{Abstract:}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-.8in}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: hang indent]

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly straight-forward if you use [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), although many other methods also exist:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum}

\title{My title}
\author{My author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\quad}X@{}}
  Abstract: &
  \lipsum[1]
\end{tabularx}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The abstract is set in an `X`-column (making it fully-justified), while the entire table has width `\textwidth` (and no indent/tabular separation).